# anybody can correct this code?

Tags: java, json

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<ProductData> getAllProductList(@QueryParam("hotel_id") int hotel_id) throws SQLException{

    System.out.println("Hotel id id==="+hotel_id);

    ProductData productData=new ProductData();
    List<ProductData> products = new ArrayList<ProductData>();

    rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from products where hotel_id="+hotel_id);

    while(rs.next()){
        productData.setProductName(rs.getString("name"));
        productData.setProductCategory(rs.getString("category"));
        productData.setProductRate(rs.getDouble("rate"));
        productData.setProductLogoPath(rs.getString("productLogoPath"));
        products.add(productData);
    }

    return products; 
}
```

I have passed List as JsonObject.Now i tried to get List value like

```
void handleResponse(String response) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("products");

}
```

but i can't get the List value.anyBody can help me?

Comment: Well, now you need to parse the JSON object back to `List<ProductData>`. What's your exact problem?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i don't know how to parse the JSON object to List<ProductData>.that is my problem friend

Comment: But have you tried something first before posting the question here?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yeah friend.i have tried more than 3 hours.but till i don't get.can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use method signature something similar like-
public Response getAllProduct..
& 
return like-
return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(products).build();

For intg. layer use-
public ClientResponse<> similarSignatureMethod..
&
call via the client and then get response entity as-
clientResponse.getEntity();

Comment: Use - javax.ws.rs.core.Response.

Comment: Use ClientResponse<String> and getEntity to get the complete list of products.

Answer (score 0):

There is the simple way to convert json string to object :

Try this :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
POJO obj = mapper.readValue(yourJSONString, POJO.class);
```

Comment: yourJSONString means my response String?

Comment: absolutely. This is the way how to parse back to object not List<Object>.

Comment: then how can i get List<Object>?

Comment: Dude just try by yourself. If I will tell you everything then you'll not get anything to learn. Go on, you can do it